# Fire function on load element with jQuery 3.X.X

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't figure out why this isn't working:

```
<p>test</p>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("p").on("load", function(){
        alert("loaded");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`p` elements do not fire a `load` event.

It's redundant for them to anyway, as if the DOM has loaded then the `p` has too. Therefore you can remove the `load()` event handler completely and work with the `p`, knowing that it is available for use.

Comment: Alright then. But can I force it to fire a `load` event anyway? I want to hide the `p` tag an when it will be available, I want to fire event. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, you can fire a custom event on the element manually: `$('p').trigger('myCustomEventNameHere')`. However if you want to hide the `p` element then you'd be much better served by using CSS: `display: none`

Comment: That's wonderful. Thanks Rory! Yes, I'm aware of CSS. I'm using a bit more complex things. Thanks once again :)

Comment: No problem, glad to help!

Comment: *"when it will be available, I want to fire event. "* - the `$(document).ready(` "event" fires when the p is available.  There's no need for another event to fire/trigger.